# SQL: Exclude weekends with certain cutoff time

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating an sql script that'll run everyday, and identify which are the orders that Missed TAT(turnaround time), and the processing hours should exclude weekends(non-working days) at the cutoff time (Start: 3AM Saturday UTC and End: 10AM UTC Monday). I put a *Deadline* column for calculating the processing hours, so when I subtract it to the *DateGenerated* it'll mark the MissedTAT orders. However, I don't know how to create the condition wherein **if the *order* is created on weekdays and run through weekends, it'll stop on the given cutoff time/it'll subtract the given cutoff time to the *Deadline* date**

**Thank you in advance**

```
use ews
DECLARE @DATENOW datetime,
        @DATEND datetime
SET @DATENOW = Convert(Date,GETDATE())
SET @DATEND =  DATEADD(MS,-3,DATEADD(HH,-2,@DATENOW ))

;WITH CTE1
AS (
Select O.OrderNumber as 'OrderNumber',
       OIT.OrderIdentifier,
       FORMAT (O.DateCreated, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', 'en-US' ) 'DateCreated',
       FORMAT (OP.DateGenerated, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', 'en-US' ) 'DateGenerated',
       AL.CompanyName
       from [Order] O
JOIN [OrderProducts] OP ON O.OrderNumber = OP.OrderNumber
LEFT JOIN [Order_Identifier_Transactional] OIT ON O.OrderNumber = OIT.OrderNumber
LEFT JOIN UsersLib UL ON O.UserID = UL.UserId
LEFT JOIN [AccountsLib] AL ON UL.RegID= AL.RegId
where OP.ProdID = 3
AND (OP.DateGenerated between Dateadd(MS,3,DATEADD(DD,0,@DATEND)) and Dateadd(dd,1,@DATEND)
or OP.DateGenerated>= DATEADD(MS,0,@DATENOW )) 
AND AL.AccountNumber != '10002619001'
),
CTE2 AS
(Select 
  FORMAT(
        CAST(
             CASE 
             WHEN UL.AccountNumber in ('10002256001','10002202001') THEN --CALCULATION FOR METRO & AZLAND
                  CASE 
                      --WEEKENDS AND CONTAIN WEEKENDS
                      WHEN DATEPART (DW, CTE1.DateCreated) IN (4,5,6)THEN DATEADD (DAY, 4, CTE1.DateCreated) -- Wednesday,Thursday, Friday
                      WHEN DATEPART (DW, CTE1.DateCreated) = 7 THEN DATEADD (DAY, 3, CTE1.DateCreated) --Saturday
                      WHEN Hl.isHoliday = 1 THEN --is Holiday FOR METRO & AZLAND
                        CASE
                        WHEN HL.DayOfWeek IN (5,6) THEN DATEADD (DAY, 4, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        WHEN HL.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD (DAY, 3, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        ELSE DATEADD (DAY,2, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        END
                      ELSE DATEADD (DAY,2, CTE1.DateCreated)
                  END
             WHEN UL.AccountNumber not in ('10002256001','10002202001') THEN  --CALCULATION FOR NON METRO & AZLAND
                  CASE
                  --WEEKENDS AND CONTAIN WEEKENDS
                      WHEN DATEPART (DW, CTE1.DateCreated) IN (5,6)THEN DATEADD (DAY, 5, CTE1.DateCreated) -- Thursday, Friday
                      WHEN DATEPART (DW, CTE1.DateCreated) = 7 THEN DATEADD (DAY, 4, CTE1.DateCreated) --Saturday
                      WHEN Hl.isHoliday = 1 THEN --is Holiday FOR NON METRO & AZLAND
                        CASE
                        WHEN HL.DayOfWeek IN (5,6) THEN DATEADD (DAY, 4, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        WHEN HL.DayOfWeek = 7 THEN DATEADD (DAY, 3, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        ELSE DATEADD (DAY,3, CTE1.DateCreated)
                        END
                  END
             END as datetime),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', 'en-US') as 'Deadline'
 ,CTE1.OrderNumber as 'OrderNumber'
 FROM [Order] O
 LEFT JOIN UsersLib UL ON O.UserID = UL.UserId
 LEFT JOIN [AccountsLib] AL ON UL.RegID= AL.RegId 
 LEFT JOIN [OrderProducts] OP ON O.OrderNumber= OP.OrderNumber
 LEFT JOIN [Holidate] HL ON CAST(HL.DateID as int) = O.OrderNumber
 RIGHT JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
 where OP.ProdID = 3
)
,CTE3 AS --another CTE, this will catch the orders that'll be created on weekends
(Select 
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(dw,CTE1.DateCreated) = 1 THEN DATEADD(HH,10,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(D,1,CONVERT(DATE,CTE1.DateCreated))))
        WHEN DATEPART(dw,CTE1.DateCreated) = 7 AND DATEPART(HH,CTE1.DateCreated) >= 3 THEN DATEADD(HH,10,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(D,2,CONVERT(DATE,CTE1.DateCreated))))
        WHEN DATEPART(dw,CTE1.DateCreated) = 2 AND DATEPART(HH,CTE1.DateCreated) <= 10 THEN DATEADD(HH,10,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,CTE1.DateCreated)))     
        ELSE CTE1.DateCreated
    END as ' '
    ,CTE1.OrderNumber as 'OrderNumber'
        FROM [Order] O
        LEFT JOIN UsersLib UL ON O.UserID = UL.UserId
        LEFT JOIN [AccountsLib] AL ON UL.RegID= AL.RegId 
        LEFT JOIN [OrderProducts] OP ON O.OrderNumber= OP.OrderNumber
        LEFT JOIN [Holidate] HL ON CAST(HL.DateID as int) = O.OrderNumber
        RIGHT JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
        where OP.ProdID = 3
)
Select b.OrderIdentifier,
       b.DateCreated,
       a.Deadline,
       b.DateGenerated,
       CASE WHEN 
       CAST(DateGenerated as datetime) > CAST(Deadline as datetime)
       AND DateGenerated is NOT NULL
       THEN 'MissedTAT'
       Else ' '
       END AS Remarks,
       b.CompanyName
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM CTE2) AS a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM CTE1) AS b 
ON a.OrderNumber = b.OrderNumber
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM CTE3) AS c
ON b.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber
;
```

Comment: There aren't an infinite number of users on SO, so creating a new login to ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550215/sql-weekend-cutoff-time) is likely to be noticed. That said, this is a much clearer description of the logic than you gave us before.

Comment: Yeah. But it was closed, because I forgot to include the sql script that I've created. Thank you